# How To GroupBy the latest record on the group

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

What laravel query would I use to groupBy('author_id') but the latest result. Right now everything I try pulls up the first result. I have tried using MAX(id) as id sql function but no luck

it finds the record ok, just finds the first record in the group

Here is my model query that I am using:

```
public function lastMessages() {
     return $this->hasMany('App\Message', 'recipient_id')->groupBy('author_id')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
}
```

I have also tried:

```
public function lastMessages() {
     return $this->hasMany('App\Message', 'recipient_id')
         ->select(DB::raw('*, max(id) as id))
         ->groupBy('author_id')
         ->orderBy('id', 'desc');
}
```

I have tried this as well and no luck:

```
public function lastMessages() {
     return $this->hasMany('App\Message', 'recipient_id')
         ->select(DB::raw('*, max(created_at) as created_at))
         ->groupBy('author_id')
         ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}
```

All of the above will return the first row of the group author_id. I'm looking to return the last row of every group or the latest row. I have also tried ->latest() and no dice!

Thanks in advance for the help.

My Table:

id
project_id
author_id
recipient_id
message
created_at
updated_at

Comment: It might help if you show some sample data along with desired output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

create a subquery join that gets each author latest message id in this way group by will be no longer need since you are already getting each author latest message id in your join subquery

max(created) is no longer need because you are already getting the latest created message in each group

```
public function lastMessages() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Message', 'recipient_id')
         ->select('*')
         ->join(DB::raw('(Select max(id) as id from messages group by author_id) LatestMessage'), function($join) {
            $join->on('messages.id', '=', 'LatestMessage.id');
            })
         ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}
```

[Screen Shot](https://gyazo.com/ededd3b47c593c8bb4b9e3b122bff08d)

Comment: OMG!! Thank you, i've been banging my head at this for the past 4 hours. I found another solution to this without using the join. I'll post the answer as well

Answer (score 4):

After banging my head at this for hours and some input from this forum, I got to this which also provides me with a desired result.

```
public function lastMessages() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Message', 'recipient_id')
        ->select('*')
        ->whereIn('id', function($q){
            $q->select(DB::raw('MAX(id) FROM messages GROUP BY author_id'));
        });
}
```

Comment: yep, but this one is slower because you are calling this subquery in every rows

Comment: how do you measure the speed of the query? I'm not the best when it comes to sql

Comment: Just prepend Explain before your query

Comment: how would you do that in laravel? through DB::Raw or is there an explain->() command

Comment: Manually input `Explain query` to your dbms

Answer (score 2):

to groupby the latest record, you can use latest & unique methods like this:

```
public function lastMessages() {
 return $this->hasMany('App\Message', 'recipient_id')->latest()->get()->unique('author_id');
}
```